# PHP Shopping Cart Without Delivery Module

Tags: open-source, html, php, mysql, shopping-cart

Basically we book services offered by individuals and products.
We don't sell any products, hence we don't need to deliver/ship anything to the customer.
Please help me find a PHP based cart software that doesn't have delivery module.
I am aware of PHP booking carts such as [Magento](http://magento.com/), [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/), [osCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/), [PrestaShop](http://www.prestashop.com/), [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) etc., but it will take more efforts to remove delivery module and related modules from these carts.

Now I want an open source web app that can:

1. add/edit/delete categories (all products belonging to one category will have common attributes like availability, pricing, name, area, contact details etc.)
2. add/edit/delete products
3. add/edit/delete category attributes, product features
4. orders, pricing
5. customers
6. NO DELIVERY/SHIPPING/MANUFACTURERS/SUPPLIERS
7. add/edit/delete admins and their roles/permissions, restricting some of the functions etc
8. and frontend resulting from above requirements.

Comment: don't all of those offer digital goods? woocommerce has an events booking module